# Magento 1.14 admin page showing 404 error

Tags: admin, magento-1, magento-enterprise, enterprise-1.14, user

We have a scenario where 5000 + admin user needs to access Magento 1.14 admin panel. It is not necessary that they will all need to access admin panel concurrently.  If a single user logs in, the page spins for a couple of minutes and then shows 404 errors.   If we delete the users to less than 300, the page loads perfectly.
Can anyone help us to resolve the issue?  Is there any restriction in creating a number of admin users?  If so, please suggest an alternative method to have 5000 + admin users.